# Issue booting Win10 with UEFI (new PC build)

Tags: windows, boot, usb, uefi, fat32

I just built a PC (specs below) and I’m having a rough time creating a bootable Windows OS USB from my Mac.

I think it’s because UEFI requires FAT32 (not exFat and NTFS). The only version of Windows Pro 64 bit available for download is 5-6gb which is too large for FAT32. I tried ExFat but I don’t believe it’s compatible with UEFI.

Can you please advise?

I don’t have access to a Windows machine to utilize the Media Creation Tool.  I also don’t have an optical drive installed. I purchased a digital license of Win10 OS on NewEgg and received the Authorization Code via email.

Can I boot using something else besides UEFI, at least initially to install Windows?

Specs:

- Ryzen 3900XT
- MSI x570 Gaming Pro Carbon
- RTX 2070 Super

(not sure what else is relevant)

Answer (score 1):

Although it’s a rather heavy-weight solution I’d suggest using a virtual machine (with Windows). That way you can utilize all sorts of tools to create and customize a Windows Setup USB. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is a suitable software to do this.

Basically, it’s somewhat like this:

1. Install VirtualBox
2. Create new VM
3. Install Windows on VM from ISO you have (don’t use any product key)
4. Connect your USB drive to the VM using USB passthrough
5. Use a tool of your choice (I recommend [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)) to create the Setup USB
6. Optionally customize it (maybe download some drivers and put them on the USB drive)
7. Test it!

When you’re down, don’t forget to completely remove the VM again because it’s large.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis is right. UEFI spec requires support for FAT family of filesystems and most vendors don't implement anything besides it. (thanks for @Akeo for clarification). Therefore NTFS support isn't universal and generally can't be relieved upon.

This limitation can be circumvented by using a [NTFS driver](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs). It's supposed to be placed on a FAT32 partition followed by a NTFS partition. You can do this by hand or use Rufus (with a Windows ISO), which is the intended way of installing this driver. Unfortunately it works only on Windows.

There's also WoeUSB for Linux, but I've never got it to work.

Microsoft's Media Creation Tool also works around the FAT limitation somehow, but I don't know how exactly.

@Daniel B's idea to prepare the installation media may be the best approach if you don't have a Windows machine at hand.

Comment: IIRC the Media Creation Tool removes editions from the `install.wim` file to save space.

Comment: Rufus dev here. Just to be pedantic, UEFI mandates that **at least** FAT should be supported, but this doesn't exclude other file systems from also being supported for boot. And the _"vendors don't implement anything besides it"_ is factually incorrect. All Intel NUC systems support booting in pure UEFI mode from NTFS, and recent Gigabyte and ASUS motherboards also have NTFS UEFI boot support (source: I have tested this).